# Can you alter the column value in a where clause during a join?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

Let's say we are joining 5 tables, A/B/C/D/E on one column each. A -> B, B -> C, C -> D, D- > E.

Let's say we have 2 columns `A.date` and `E.date`.

We want joins only to occur where `E.date` is between `A.date` and `A.date + 1.day`.

Is there anyway to do this without adding a column to A for `A.date + 1.day`?

essentially something like .where("A.date < E.date AND (A.date + 1.day) > E.date")

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using Postgresql

Comment: Perhaps it's just a bad example, but how could `A.date < E.date AND (A.date + 1.day) > E.date` ever be true?

Comment: @Turophile A.date could be today at 1pm. E.date could be today at 2pm.

Comment: @chrisP No, a `date` datatype is just a date. You gave no indication these columns are `timestamp`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE A.date <= E.date AND E.date <= A.date + intervall '1day';
```

Just replace the [...] with the appropriate code. You should be able to use a BETWEEN, but it will be basically the same.

Comment: do you know the syntax in Rails?

Comment: @chrisP Just a guess, but I think (using your example) the Rails syntax would be `.where("A.date < E.date AND (A.date + interval '1.day') > E.date")`

Answer (score 1):

You will be checking with only A.Date and A.Date+1, correct?
So you can try this...
You don't actually need to use BETWEEN

```
[your code]
WHERE
   (A.Date=E.Date OR
   DATEADD(day,1,A.Date)=E.Date)
```

Comment: I don't think that postgreSQL has a `DATEADD()` function.http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html